# Is there an @Html.ActionLink equivilent for HttpPost?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a table that I need to add links to. The links need to go to an HTTPPost actionResult on my controller. I have a huge list that the user needs to be allowed to click on the status, hit the controller and route to the appropriate page afterward. @Html.ActionLink is an HttpGet action. Is there an equivalent for a post?

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <th>Ssn</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>File Uploaded Date</th>
        <th>Claim Status</th>
        @foreach (var currentClaim in Model.CurrentClaims)
        {
        <tr >
            <td><span name="Ssn">@currentClaim.SSN</span></td>
            <td>@currentClaim.StateName</td>
            <td>@currentClaim.ClaimDate</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(@currentClaim.ClaimStatus, "SubmitClaim", "Claim", FormMethod.Post, new ClaimInputModel { SSN = currentClaim.SSN, StateId = currentClaim.StateId })</td>

         </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

I tried using

```
 @using("SubmitClaim", "Claim", FormMethod.Post, new ClaimInputModel { SSN = currentClaim.SSN, StateId = currentClaim.StateId })
 {
      <button type="submit" >xxx</button>
 }
```

I get an HttpCompiler error with this.

Comment: Your using statement is not well formed.  What "HttpCompiler" error are you getting?

Comment: try `@using(Html.BeginForm(...))`

Comment: @dotjoe add that comment as an answer and I will accept it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `BeginForm()` HtmlHelper that returns a `MvcForm` which implements `IDisposable`...

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("SubmitClaim", "Claim", FormMethod.Post, new { SSN = currentClaim.SSN, StateId = currentClaim.StateId }))
{
     <button type="submit" >xxx</button>
}
```